# jQuery GREP + JSON empty data filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file and I'm injecting the data into an HTML page.
I would like to filter out any empty object array that's coming back from the JSON file.

My code is below - should I use GREP maybe?

```
  $(data.content).each(function(index, content){
      $("#htmlID").append('<span>' + content.myinfo + ');
    });
        {

        "content": 

        [ 
    {"myinfo":"Bill Clinton 095 years old. "},
    {" "},
    {"myinfo":"Bill Clinton 295 years old. "},
    {" "}

        ]
        }
```

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense. What's `{" "}` supposed to be?

Comment: I'm guessing that's the "empty array object" the OP is talking about.

Comment: Assuming this is not a typo, what you posted is not valid JSON; you should be formatting it better at the source otherwise it won't parse right in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just ignore empty data? Something like this?

```
$(data.content).each(function(index, content){
    if(!(typeof content.myinfo === "undefined" ||
      content.myinfo.length<1)){
      $("#htmlID").append('<span>' + content.myinfo);
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited the code, missed that you were already iterating data.content. This should work. Yes, you could probably use grep to the same effect.

But, as stated in your JSON you have {""}, which is invalid. That will prevent the JSON from being correctly parsed. And in that case neither this, nor grep would help.

Comment: Ok, then the above should work fine; or you could use grep on the array.

Answer (score 0):

A part from the {" "} syntax error (was it meant to be just '{}'?) the only proper way to do this is using a parser to iterate the object and remove what's not needed.

This could be done using `jQuery.parseJSON( json )` (see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) that also ensures there is no malicious code that gets executed in the JSON string.

Other ways, such as removing lines matching a regexp, are just quite bad hacks that could lead to many problems in some non-standard scenarios.

**EDIT:**
I see there's also this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ to convert back the JS object into a JSON string.

Anyways, I'm not sure about what your actual need is (what's inside `content.myinfo`? why are you building that HTML+JSON code that way? How is the JSON string generated?)

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com), your JSON is not valid.

The empty objects in your JSON should be like this:

```
{" ": ""}
```

Changing both empty objects to the form above makes your string valid JSON and this should parse.